# Converter shows System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies when bind to EF Model

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding, imultivalueconverter

I am writing a WPF MVVM Application.  I am trying to use a converter to display a contact name in the combobox.  I do not think I can use the DisplayMemberPath since a "fullname" column does not exist.

The ComboBox is being bound to a class within a class using Entity Framework.  Given the following:

.cs Files

```
public class Car
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public Contact Owner { get; set; }
}

public class Contact 
{
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public string Salutation { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Suffix { get; set; }
}

public class MultiBindingConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string name = "";
        if (!(values[0] is Contact Contact))
            return name;

        switch ((string)parameter)
        {
            case "LastNameFirst":
            name += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Contact.LastName)) ? Contact.LastName : "";
            name += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Contact.Suffix)) ? " " + Contact.Suffix : "";
            name += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Contact.FirstName)) ? ", " + Contact.FirstName : "";
            name += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Contact.MiddleName)) ? " " + Contact.MiddleName : "";
            name += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Contact.Salutation)) ? ", " + Contact.Salutation : "";

            break;
        case "FormatNormal":
        default:
            name += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Contact.Salutation)) ? Contact.Salutation : "";
            name += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Contact.FirstName)) ? " " + Contact.FirstName : "";
            name += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Contact.MiddleName)) ? " " + Contact.MiddleName : "";
            name += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Contact.LastName)) ? " " + Contact.LastName : "";
            name += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Contact.Suffix)) ? " " + Contact.Suffix : "";
            break;
    }

    return name;
}

public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
}
```

.XAML file

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:MultiBindingConverter x:Key="MBC" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts, Mode=OneTime}" // Contacts is a full list of the Contact Class (so its every Owner)
          SelectedValuePath="ContactId"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Car.Owner.ContactId, Mode=TwoWay}"
          >
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock>
             <TextBlock.Text>
                  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MBC}" ConverterParameter="LastNameFirst" >
                      <Binding Path="Contacts"/>
                  </MultiBinding>
             </TextBlock.Text>
         </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
 </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ComboBox>
```

The issue is that the end result that is displayed in the ComboBox is:

> System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Contact_.......

It is not showing the Owner name in the correct format.  How can I do a binding to the ComboBox in this manner to get the output I desire (ie. Doe Sr., John Michael, Mr.)

***EDIT***
I have also tried it this way

.cs IValueConverter

```
public class ContactNameConverter : BaseValueConverter<ContactNameConverter>
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        string name = "";
        if (!(value is Contact Contact))
            return name;

        switch ((string)parameter)
        {
            case "LastNameFirst":
                name += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Contact.LastName)) ? Contact.LastName : "";
                name += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Contact.Suffix)) ? " " + Contact.Suffix : "";
                name += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Contact.FirstName)) ? ", " + Contact.FirstName : "";
                name += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Contact.MiddleName)) ? " " + Contact.MiddleName : "";
                name += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Contact.Salutation)) ? ", " + Contact.Salutation : "";

                break;
            case "FormatNormal":
            default:
                name += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Contact.Salutation)) ? Contact.Salutation : "";
                name += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Contact.FirstName)) ? " " + Contact.FirstName : "";
                name += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Contact.MiddleName)) ? " " + Contact.MiddleName : "";
                name += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Contact.LastName)) ? " " + Contact.LastName : "";
                name += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Contact.Suffix)) ? " " + Contact.Suffix : "";
                break;
        }

        return name;

    }

    public override object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

.XAML

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts, Mode=OneTime}"
      SelectedValuePath="ContactId"
      SelectedValue="{Binding Car.Owner.ContactId, Mode=TwoWay}"
      >
      <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=., Converter={local:ContactNameConverter}}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
      </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies` is used by EF as a proxy to enable lazy loading. You can disable proxy creation by setting `ObjectContext.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled` to false. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9501732/366064)

However, it is recommended to use ViewModels as the source of the binding instead of EF Models.

You can also add a new property to an EF Model (or preferably to a VM) as the source of the bindings of each item:

```
 [NotMapped]
 public string FirstLastName { get { return FirstName + ", " + LastName; } }
```

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18114659/366064)

---

You should keep in mind that `DataContext` of `ItemTemplate` refers to each element of a collection. So the path of an object of type `Contact` is `.` not `Contacts`.

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock>
             <TextBlock.Text>
                  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MBC}" ConverterParameter="LastNameFirst" >
                      <Binding Path="."/>
                  </MultiBinding>
             </TextBlock.Text>
         </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
 </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

I also noticed that you used a multi value converter with one value. You could do it like the following:

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock>
             <TextBlock.Text>
                  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MBC}" ConverterParameter="LastNameFirst" >
                      <Binding Path="FirstName"/>
                      <Binding Path="LastName"/>
                  </MultiBinding>
             </TextBlock.Text>
         </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
 </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
     if(parameter == "LastNameFirst")
        return string.Format("{0}, {1}", values[0], values[1]);
     else
        return string.Format("{0}, {1}", values[1], values[0]);
}
```

Comment: I tried both of those.  I ended up with the same result.  I did however edit my post to show another way I was attempting it using an IValueConverter instead.  Still reach the same result.

Comment: @Red_Phoenix have you tried overriding ToString() in Contact?

Comment: I have.  But I could only get it to return one format: public override string ToString()

{

   return $"{FirstName} {LastName}";

}.   How would you use the converter with a parameter to indicate the format?

Comment: @Red_Phoenix using another property. BTW take a look at this post : https://stackoverflow.com/q/18069889/366064

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer for the reason that @Bijan provided the link above to another question.  Since I am using Entity Framework this seems alot easier than using bindings and converters.

Comment: @Red_Phoenix thank you. you may also take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9501732/366064 I added some notes to my answer